# Spring Hibernate Double ID Every Server Restart

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot

I have multiple entity and all their Id fields set with this. And I am using Spring Data JPA btw.

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
```

When I restart Tomcat every time DB's ID column double itself like this. And entity doesnt matter. All table's ID like this. Not only this one.

[image]

As you see Id column change sequence itself. I delete all the DB and try again, but not working.

Comment: Deleting all db doesn't help? Yes it's not working.

Comment: @RomanC no, doesn't help.

Comment: What hibernate version?

Comment: I am using Spring Data JPA which it use Hibernate 4.3.11.